# file_get_contents failure on windows

Tags: php, windows, command-line-interface, file-get-contents, file-put-contents

I have a PHP CLI application that creates a file with file_put_contents then listens for changes to that file.  If the filemtime changes then I try to get the content with file_get_contents.  It often fails to retrieve the contents on windows.  This baffles me.  How is it possible that a process that creates the file cannot open the file?

I even ran icacls on the folder that the file is in and it still fails to have access to read the file that it created.

```
icacls.exe 'MYFOLDER' /grant MYUSER:(OI)(CI)F /T
```

Can someone please enlighten me on how to insure a PHP process can read a file it created?

Comment: No code and no error == nobody has any idea.

Comment: Best guess: whatever external process caused the file to change has an exclusive handle to the file open.  Quickest fix would be to add a small delay after you notice the change, but you should probably be doing this in a loop.

Comment: I solved the problem by having PHP run a Perl script that returns the contents the file. Using Perl I was also able to remove the icacls call. So either Perl does not care that another program has an exclusive lock or there is something wrong with PHP's file_get_contents function on Windows.